# Some problems to pass XML from client to server

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to sent XML using ajax to my action method:

```
    function CreateBuffer() {
        var xmlSel = parent.parent.mapFrame.GetSelectionXML();
        alert(xmlSel);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '../../TaskPanel/CreateBuffer',
            data: { "SESSION": '@ViewBag.SESSION', "MAPNAME": '@ViewBag.LAYOUT', "SELECTION": xmlSel },
            success: function (result) {
                parent.parent.ZoomToView(-87.708421, 43.745046, 7196.85673, true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Using this row in Action method on server to retrive XML:

```
    public void CreateBuffer()
    {
       String selectionXml = Request.Params["SELECTION"];
    }
```

But value of selectionXml  is NULL!

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Show the method signature of your Action method and your route definitions.

Comment: Can you try it without the doublequotes around the querystring parameter/property names, as in: `data: { SESSION: '@ViewBag.SESSION', MAPNAME: '@ViewBag.LAYOUT', SELECTION: xmlSel },` to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @David, I trayed  and now i have this error:  A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Comment: The message should indicate which querystring parameter had the offending values, and it is likely the XML.  Can you try submitting a simple string literal rather than the XML to make sure that your value is making it to the Action method.  If it is ok, then you need to address being able to accept XML without flagging the 'potentially dangerous request' issue.